# Transforming data or not

Tags: data-transformation, elastic-net

I have data that I will use as a feature to Elastic Net. I thought I should transform the data using either Box Cox or Yeo Johnson.
The transformed data looks weird and I'm not sure if I should transform the data or not.
[image]

Besides the large bar at -2 for Yeo Johnson the distribution looks ok, but I'm not sure if large amount of values around -2 will affect model performance or not.

So my question is, is it always safe to transform the data? I.e. can it affect model performance, in a negative way, by transforming the data?

Comment: Some implementations normalize the data by default, so be careful not to overnormalize. Standardization is often the #1 choice.

Comment: You do not need normal distributions for predictor variables. (You do not need a normal distribution for the response variable, either. When regressions make a normality assumption,  it is about the error term, not any of the marginal distributions.)